# Replace function call with anonymous method

Tags: c#-4.0, anonymous-methods

I feel stupid. Can you guys help me to replace **GetCamp(x)** with anonymous?

**This code:**

```
   aspnet_Users.ForEach(x =>
        {
            usersVm.Add(new User{
                 Camp = Mapper.Map<DbCamp, Camp>(GetCamp(x)),
            });
        }); 


    private DbCamp GetCamp(aspnet_Users x)
    {
        //... some code ...
        return someDbCamp;
    }
```

**Should be something like this:**

```
   aspnet_Users.ForEach(x =>
    {
         usersVm.Add(new User{
              Camp = Mapper.Map<DbCamp, Camp>
              (
                    Func<DbCamp>(aspnet_Users u) => 
                    { 
                         //... some code ...
                          return someDbCamp;
                    }
               ),
           });
     });
```

That doesn't work because `Mapper.Map<Database.Camp, Camp>` expects an object `typeof(DbCamp)` as a parameter, not a delegate. I can use a normal function of course but from academical standpoint, I wonder if it's possible to use anonymous method here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should handle the empty case.

```
x => x.Users.Any() ? x.Users.First().Camp : null
```

In context:

```
_dataContext.aspnet_Users.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        usersVm.Add(new User{
             Camp = Mapper.Map<Database.Camp, Camp>(
                  x => x.Users.Any() ? x.Users.First().Camp : null),
        });
    });
```

Comment: It works although still doesn't answer the question... How to make it anonymous... using Func<> or whatever

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can just paste that in place of GetCamp(x). Is that not what you meant?

Comment: I mean the question is academical... If I needed to check for null I would just ask for that. I need to replace entire GetCamp() with anonymous. Regardless of that anonymous method functionality. Updated the question again

Comment: @Agzam: It can be used anonymously. I updated my answer to show how.

Comment: I want something like  Camp = Mapper.Map<Database.Camp, Camp>( x => {
  //here goes something
}
But it doesn't let me

Comment: It says Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Database.Camp' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Agzam: You'll have to provide more code.  It shouldn't be attempting to convert the lambda to a Camp.  There must be something else going on in some of the other code.

Comment: Mapper.Map<Database.Camp, Camp>() expects Database.Camp object as a parameter. Not lambda not a delegate. I believe if I can leverage that to outer function which returns Database.Camp object, I can transform the outer function into an anonymous method. Using Func<> or something like that. I just don't know how it should look like syntactically

Comment: @Agzam: I don't understand what you mean by outer function or where you want to use an anonymous method.  Without more context, this is the best I can do, although I can see now that there's a type error in it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work:

```
x => GetCamp(x)
```

?

Comment: I need to have a check because FirstOrDefault can be null. I updated the question

Comment: You shouldn't update questions like that... should just close/accept the answer and make a new question.  Otherwise you end up with useless answers hanging off of questions they don't seem to fit.

Comment: Edited, is that what you're looking for??

Comment: I want to transform GetCamp function into an anonymous something like this: () => { return Camp}. this doesn't work of course because Mapper.Map<Database.Camp, Camp>() expects Database.Camp object as a parameter. Not lambda expression, not a delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
aspnet_Users.ForEach(x =>
{
    usersVm.Add(new User{ Camp = Mapper.Map<DbCamp, Camp>({ /*... some code using x ...*/ return someDbCamp; }) });
});
```